# Media Query not formatting correctly with Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, media-queries

I am running into a very odd situation. I believe it to be occurring in Safari, but not 100% sure. It is only happening in my 640 or less media query. What is wrong is when the device gets into that viewport (640px or less) my boxes should be 2 columns and 2 rows, just like it is doing in the jsfiddle. It is working like this mostly everywhere, except like I said in Safari, even with Chrome developer tools open with the iPhone6 responsive toolbar open the issue isn't occurring.

[Click here to see it in a jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/nh99mcex/)

When the problem occurs it looks like this:

The B is moved to the 2nd row and it looks as if `margin-left` is being applied and my `margin-right: 0` is not taking effect.

[image]

However, I have the following in the media query.

```
.marketing-service:nth-child(2) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.marketing-service:nth-child(3) {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Does `nth-child()` not work in Safari?

Does anyone else know what could be happening for this to not work right for Safari?

```js
$('#marketing-tab1').addClass('active');
 $('#marketing1').show();
 
 //For tabs to stay active
 $('.marketing-service').click(function() {
  $('.marketing-service.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  
  //To get the service display box to show
  var item_number = $(this).attr('id').replace('marketing-tab', '');
  /* $('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: $("#service-display-box").offset().top
   }, 1500);*/
  $('#marketing'+item_number).show().siblings('.marketing-service-section').hide();
 });
```

```css
#marketing-services {
 width: 80%;
 margin: 0 10%;
}
.marketing-service {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 22%;
 margin: 0 2%;
 height: 400px;
 background: #F0F0F0;
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
}
.marketing-service:first-child {
 margin-left: 0;
}
.marketing-service:last-child {
 margin-right: 0;
}
.marketing-service:hover {
 background: rgba(0, 255, 170, .4);
 z-index: 1;
}
.marketing-service-wrap {
 padding: 10%;
 width: 80%;
}
.marketing-service-title {
 font-size: 1.6em;
 margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.marketing-img {
 width: 125px;
 height: 125px;
}
/*-- Down Arrow for boxes --*/
.marketing-service.active, #marketing-tab1.active {
 background: rgba(0, 255, 170, .4);
}
.marketing-service.active:after, .marketing-service.active:before, #marketing-tab1.active:after, #marketing-tab1.active:before {
 top: 100%;
 left: 50%;
 border: solid transparent;
 content: " ";
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 position: absolute;
}
.marketing-service.active:after, #marketing-tab1.active:after {
 border-width: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 border-color: rgba(0, 255, 170, .4);
 border-right-color: rgba(0, 255, 170, .4);
 margin-top: -30px;
}
.marketing-service.active:before, #marketing-tab1.active:before {
 border-color: transparent;
 border-top-color: rgba(0, 255, 170, .4);
 border-width: 36px;
 margin-left: -36px;
 margin-top: 0;
}
@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
/*--- Marketing Service Tabs -----*/
#marketing-services {
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
}
.marketing-service {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 45%;
 margin: 25px 5%;
 height: 250px;
}
.marketing-service:nth-child(2) {
 margin-right: 0;
}
.marketing-service:nth-child(3) {
 margin-left: 0;
}
.marketing-service-wrap {
 padding: 5%;
 width: 90%;
}
.marketing-service-title {
 font-size: 1.3em;
 margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.marketing-img {
 width: 75px;
 height: 75px;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="marketing-services">
   <div class="marketing-service" id="marketing-tab1">
    <div class="marketing-service-wrap total-center">
     <h2 class="marketing-service-title">A</h2>
     <img src="../images/marketing-seo.png" class="marketing-img">
    </div>
   </div><div class="marketing-service" id="marketing-tab2">
    <div class="marketing-service-wrap total-center">
     <h2 class="marketing-service-title">B</h2>
     <img src="../images/marketing-ppc.png" class="marketing-img">
    </div>
   </div><div class="marketing-service" id="marketing-tab3">
    <div class="marketing-service-wrap total-center">
     <h2 class="marketing-service-title">C</h2>
     <img src="../images/marketing-conversion.png" class="marketing-img">
    </div>
   </div><div class="marketing-service" id="marketing-tab4">
    <div class="marketing-service-wrap total-center">
     <h2 class="marketing-service-title">D</h2>
     <img src="../images/marketing-email.png" class="marketing-img">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I am currently running Safari Version 10.0.2 (12602.3.12.0.1). At first, I did not change your fiddle and the view is as you expected / described (A and B aligned). Have you tried changing the @media query? I changed the media query to `@media screen and (max-width:768px)` and thought it responded a bit better.

Comment: The media query works with every other type of device, so not sure.